# How can I run a shell script from my git repository using Azure CLI to create Terraform resources on Azure?

Tags: azure-cli, azureshell, tfstate

How execute a shell script which is in my git repository through azure cli to create resources on Azure like remote storage account for Terraform state files and an Azure AD group for AKS admins

I tried to perform git clone in azure cli and then run the script present manually. But received errors like below:
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'
Also, Ideally there should be a way to directly run scripts present on a github account with azure cli.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Cli is focused on interacting with the Azure control plane.
It's not a script execution mechanism, although it can create services that will run bash scripts and that integrate with GitHub repos.

The [Azure Cloudshell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/get-started/azure-portal/cloud-shell) will be more geared to what you need. You can use bash, it comes with mounted storage for Git repos and tf state files.